CMake не видит Qt6Config.cmake
не могу сбилдить проект с Qt, не находит конфигурационный файл Qt6Config.cmake, пути прописал правильные, вместо CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH уже писал Qt6_DIR как в ошибке и говорилось но все равно та же ошибка, гпт советовал в bashrc прописать export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6" но тоже не помогло
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(typing-speedtest VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/lib/cmake/Qt6")  

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCES
    main.cpp
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.ui
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets)

Ошибка:

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):   By not providing
"FindQt6.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake to
find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6", but   CMake did
not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6" with
any of   the following names:
Qt6Config.cmake
qt6-config.cmake   Add the installation prefix of "Qt6" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt6_DIR"   to a directory containing one of
the above files.  If "Qt6" provides a   separate development package
or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


CMake говорит, что у Вас скорее всего не установлен dev-пакет. как его установить зависит от дистрибутива Вашей ОС.

dev пакеты установлены

По-моему у вас CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH не туда показывает. Я не помню точно, как на линуксе там лежит, но вот так у меня на маке - -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Users/dmitriy/Qt/6.4.3/macos Qt, потом версия, потом платформа. Другие переменные указывать не надо
